# Best way to validate request params sails.js / node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, validation, sails.js

Currently I'm implementing an application using Sails.JS. Every time REST Request hit's my sails controller, I'm manually (if else checks) checking validations like if variable exist or not / if its valid data type or not.

Is there any standard way (custom middle ware to validate each request against pre defined JSON objects?) to validate parameters as its over heading my controller logic.

How is it handled in other programming languages / frameworks in production use?

Thanks in advance.
Prasad.CH

Comment: You can use sails.js policies. which you can create in api/policies
and set policies for controllers in config/policies

Answer (score 2):

Sails.js is built on top of Express, so it seems you're looking for something like [express-validator](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator) that is an express middleware. You can also use it along with the Sails policies, as waza007 suggested.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution for me is https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv
It's a JSON schema validator
Short example:

```
var Ajv = require('ajv');
var ajv = Ajv();
var schema = {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "foo": { "type": "number" },
    "bar": { "type": "string" }
  },
  "required": [ "foo", "bar" ]
};

var data = { "foo": 1 };

var valid = ajv.validate(schema, data);

if (!valid) {
  return res.send(400, ajv.errorsText(), ajv.errors);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was fed up with in built validators in sails. Don't know why it never occurred to me that I can try an external package.

Answer (score 0):

express-validator is one option, but I prefer to do most of my validation directly in my ODM (Mongoose). For example:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var validate = require('mongoose-validator');

var nameValidator = [
    validate({
        validator: 'isLength',
        arguments: [3, 50],
        message: 'Name should be between {ARGS[0]} and {ARGS[1]} characters',
        type: 'isLength'
    }),
    validate({
        validator: 'isAscii',
        passIfEmpty: true,
        message: 'Name should contain Ascii characters only',
        type: 'isAscii'
    })
];

var todoSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        validate: nameValidator
    },
    completed: {type: Boolean, required: true}
});
```

Then you can handle the error object such a way:

```
router.post('/newTodo', handlers.newTodo, validationMonad(handlers.getTodos));
```

If Mongoose returns a validation error when creating the new document in handlers.newTodo, then it is passed to the validation handler which in turn will parse it, append the parsed error to the response and call the getTodos handler, which will show the errors in res.errors.

```
exports.validationMonad = function (reqHandler) {
    return function (err, req, res, next) {
        if (!res.errors) res.errors = [];
        switch (err.name) {
            case 'ValidationError':
                for (field in err.errors) {
                    switch (err.errors[field].kind) {
                        case 'required':
                            res.errors.push({
                                name: err.errors[field].name,
                                message: "The field '" + err.errors[field].path + "' cannot be empty.",
                                kind: err.errors[field].kind,
                                path: err.errors[field].path
                            });
                            break;
                        default:
                            res.errors.push({
                                name: err.errors[field].name,
                                message: err.errors[field].message,
                                kind: err.errors[field].kind,
                                path: err.errors[field].path
                            });
                    }
                }
                if (reqHandler) {
                    reqHandler(req, res, next);
                } else {
                    // JSON
                    res.json(res.errors[0])
                }
                break;
            case 'CastError':
                // Supplied ID is not an ObjectID
                res.errors.push({
                    name: err.name,
                    message: err.message,
                    kind: err.kind,
                    path: err.path
                });
                if (reqHandler) {
                    reqHandler(req, res, next);
                } else {
                    // JSON
                    res.json(res.errors)
                }
                break;
            default:
                return next(err)
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Doe this work with waterline returned model validation erros? i don't think so. is there any specific solution for waterline / sails.js solutions?

Comment: This is obviously for Mongoose, but the same concept should apply for any other ORM: do the validation into the ORM (not with express-validator or other similar tools), then catch the error with a request handler and process it to make it suitable for your templates. This is the best approach to validation IMHO.